# How can I POST a multipart HTTP request from Perl to Java and get a response?

Tags: perl, post, httprequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to post from one of my subroutines in Perl a request to a Java based controller.
But I'm not getting any kind of response back. I know the Java code works file because I can get a response if I post to it from a HTML form.

This is my Perl code:

```
  use HTTP::Request::Common;
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

  my $response = $ua->request(POST 'http://testserver/testing.nc',
        Content_Type => 'form-data',
        Content => [
            method => 'submit',
            ftp_server => 'ftp.localhost',
            ftp_user => 'testuser',
            ftp_password => 'testpass',
            remote_path => '/home/files',
            port => 22,
            file_to_upload => ["$file"]
  ]);
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Why are there lines for ftp_server ?  Are you using http or ftp? If you intend to post a file that is on a ftp site to a web server, doesn't that need to be done in two steps? I'm confused.

Comment: My guess is the `testing.nc` script is supposed to transfer the file to the FTP site.

Comment: Maybe.  If he wants to upload a file and he has access to an ftp server, and knows the user/password of the ftp server, he could use a perl module to do that transfer directly if he wanted and/or the employer allows it.  Goe -- do you know what this code or script is supposed to do when working properly?

Answer (score 6):

Posted data [must be of type `multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

**Edit:** OK, so it turns out, specifying `form-data` is enough as mentioned in the [HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Request::Common) docs:

> The POST method also supports the `multipart/form-data` content used for Form-based File Upload as specified in RFC 1867. You trigger this content format by specifying a content type of `form-data`  as one of the request headers.

However, to use `HTTP::Request::Common::POST` the way you are using, you will need to import `POST`:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
```

or use `$ua->post`:

> The `post(...)` method of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::UserAgent) exists as a shortcut for `$ua->request(POST ...)`.

You can make your life easier by using [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize). See also [this upload example](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize::Examples#pb-upload%2c_by_John_Beppu).

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I define the Content_Type asd 'form-data' at line 5

Comment: "form-data" != "multipart/form-data"

Comment: Well, I took this example from: "http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/libwww-perl/HTTP/Request/Common.pm.html#POST_url_Header_gt_Value_Content_gt_" and they use "form-data" plus there' no comma between POST and the actual URL

Comment: OK, I'm using $ua->post now. Since I'm trying to post the request within the same application is there a way to use the relative path for the url like: $ua->post('testing.nc') , when I tried that I get the "path has to be absolute" in the response.